# Was Jake Sisko the author of anything other than "Anslem"?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-eu

"*Anslem*" was authored by Jake Sisko and was referred to several times during the course of DS9.  Do we know if he was the author of any other works?  Is his writing referenced in any books or the EU?

Comment: He had a mildly successful writing career in an alternate universe. And he was a journalist for the Federation news service during the war.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Within the main timeline, we don't see him *complete* Anslem, nor do we learn if he wrote anything else besides some articles for the Federation News Service, a short story called "[Past Prologue](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Past_Prologue)" (which Nog notes isn't very good) and some poetry

> **JAKE:** *Yeah... Mrs. O'Brien used to say  that Mardah should try to get some of her stories published.*
>
> **MARDAH:** *Jake... they aren't that good. **Nothing like your poetry**.*
>
> <sub><sup>[DS9: The Abandoned](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/452.txt)</sup></sub>

There's also a short story (about a Macquis operation) that Jake gives to his father to read in [DS9: Explorers](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Explorers_%28episode%29)

> **JAKE:** *What did you think about the part where Jared thinks he's been betrayed?*
>
> **SISKO:** *I'm not sure he'd confront Iko about it... at least not right away.*
>
> ...
>
> **JAKE:** *What I mean is... yesterday I got a  communication from the Pennington School in New Zealand... they offered me a writing
> fellowship...*

---

In the alternate timeline created by the temporal accident in [DS9: The Visitor](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/476.txt), we learn that he completed two books; Anslem and a book of collected short stories:

> **MELANIE:** *It made me want to read everything you'd ever written, but when I looked, all I could find were your  "Collected Stories." **I couldn't  believe it. I'd finally found someone whose writing I really admired, and he'd only published two books.***
>
> **OLD JAKE:** *Not much to show for a life's work, is it? I'm going to get us some tea.*

Anslem was considered to be one of the 24th Century's greatest works of fiction and the Collected Stories won a number of prestigious awards including the Betar Prize.

Comment: There is a book or story that Jake wrote prior/during [Explorers](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Explorers_%28episode%29) that Sisko reads while they're on the light-ship. I don't know if if it is ever titled.

Comment: @Xantec - That book was so bad, his father took to wearing a beard so that people wouldn't recognise him in the street...

Comment: @Valorum- Then there's the fact that some nuts made him the centre of their religion. If it were me I think I'd want to hide too.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there's a real-world book listing him as a co-author, Star Trek Online: The Needs of the Many.

Here's the blurb:

> Prior to the terror-filled times of the Long War—the seemingly endless struggle against the Undine, a paranoid, shape-shifting race once known only as Species 8472—enemy sleeper agents quietly penetrated every echelon of Federation society, as well as other starfaring civilizations throughout the Alpha and Beta quadrants. The ensuing conflict shook humanity to its very core, often placing its highest ideals against a pure survival instinct. All too frequently, the Undine War demanded the harshest of sacrifices and exacted the steepest of personal costs from the countless millions whose lives the great interdimensional clash forever altered.
>
> Drawn from his exhaustive research and interviews, The Needs of the Many delivers a glimpse of Betar Prize–winning author Jake Sisko’s comprehensive "living history" of this tumultuous era. With collaborator Michael A. Martin, Sisko illuminates an often-poorly-understood time, an age marked indelibly by both fear and courage—not to mention the willingness of multitudes of unsung heroes who became the living embodiment of the ancient Vulcan philosopher Surak’s famous axiom, "The needs of the many outweigh the needs of the few."

[The Needs of the Many review](http://trekmovie.com/2010/03/31/library-computer-review-of-star-trek-online-the-needs-of-the-many-more-trek-book-news/)